# Use count on a table

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table which has the data as follows:-

ExtensionRequestId  PipelineId

```
   1                1
   2                1
   3                2
   4                1
   5                2
   6                3
```

Now i want to count the number of PipelineId reapeated.
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select pipelineId, count(pipelineId) from table group by pipelineId`

Here `table` is the name of your table!